# Error:java: Annotation processor 'org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor' not found

Tags: jhipster

When I run application.java:

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0_45 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'bookstore'
Information:2015/5/29 17:35 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5 sec
Error:java: Annotation processor 'org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor' not found
```

Comment: but mvn spring-boot:run is correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

That fixes the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Mappings({
   @Mapping(target = "", source = ""),
   @Mapping(target = "", source = "")
})
```

This fixed my error

Comment: This was the issue when I upgraded from Spring Boot 2.2 to 2.7. I was using 2 separate @Mapping, had to include them in one @Mappings({}) as you mentioned